# Fonts Disappear from Word after reboot

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-word-2013

After installing TTF CAC Shishoni Brush and rebooting the computer, Word 2013 no longer sees the font.  Only after reinstalling the font will Word see it.  The font remains in the Windows/Fonts folder.  Something amiss in Word?

Running Windows 7 Pro 32 bit

Comment: This happens repeatedly?

Comment: If this is happening repeatedly as @fixer1234 has asked, then the first thing you should try is a repair of the Office installation. You can do this from the `Add/Remove Programs` section of the `Control Panel` by right-clicking on the Office 2013 install and selecting `Change...`. Let this run and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the thought michael-frank.  Unforts it didn't work.

Comment: I did manage to follow most of the suggestions to run cmd prompt as administrator as suggested in: http://www.bohack.com/2011/04/allowing-non-administrators-to-install-fonts-in-windows-7/ however I didn't really know how the last action should be achieved or what it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a resume of what I did to fix it:
Firstly I had no access to the font folder (C:\Windows\Fonts). And no write access to the registry.
The steps I took:

1. To rectify this I ran a CMD prompt as administrator with: **attrib -r -s c:\Windows\Fonts**
2. I ran **takeown /f c:\Windows\Fonts /r /d n** (still in the cmd prompt).
3. **cacls c:\Windows\Fonts /e /t /g users:c**
4. **cacls c:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT /e /t /g users:c**
5. I pasted the CAC file to the root of C:\ and ran: **XCOPY c:\CAC.ttf %systemroot%\Fonts**
6. add to the registry, **REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v "CAC TT (True Type)" /t REG_SZ /d "CAC.ttf" /f**

This gave me the ablitiy to access the font folder in c:\Window\Fonts and the ability to access and modify the Registry, even by running regedit as a user.
All I then had to do was rename CAC file to CAC.ttf and now Word picks it up after a computer reboot.   Thanks to two URLs: http://www.bohack.com/2011/04/allowing-non-administrators-to-install-fonts-in-windows-7/ and http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/28817-installing-fonts-via-command-line-script.html  which in combination and with a bit of playing around I made it work for me.